# Restoring an HP Pavilion dv6 to factory after Linux install

Tags: system-restore, hp-pavilion

I have HP Pavilion dv6-2150us laptop. I recently installed Linux on it and now want to go back to Windows 7 (which came pre-installed). In order to take it to the factory default I used my recovery DVD disks. It completes 3 DVD restoration and when I reboot I get following error **"restoration incomplete"** with three buttons "Save Log", "show error" and "retry".

However, when I click on retry it asks for DVD-1 then ejects it and takes me to the same screen. Save log saves a zip file log on pen drive which is password protected and I cannot open and see it. The show error button does not show any error.

In the past I have restored my system back using these DVDs. I also have an additional set of recovery disks and I have tried using both with same error. I have Acer netbook as well and if I use its recovery disk on HP laptop it restores perfectly but to Acer defaults with Windows starter edition.

How do I restore my HP pavilion back to factory condition?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Nuke the drive](http://www.dban.org/) before you use the restore discs.

If you are using HP branded recovery discs (not ones you made on your PC) and have a problem recovering after nuking the hard drive, [see this page.](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/softwareDownloadIndex?softwareitem=pv-80183-1&cc=us&lc=en&dlc=en)

Comment: Thanks Moab, for past 2-3 days I was fighting with this problem. I just used the dban.org's iso and wrote zero's on entire disk. This fixed the issue and now my restoration process from recovery disk has started.

Comment: Glad to be of help. Its a long process be patient.